# TypeError: ('Not JSON Serializable:', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=123.0>)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a *production* model which is configurable over a `ModelConfig`  I wrote myself which itself is a `class Config(dict)`. In that `ModelConfig` I am setting `hidden_size=123`. The following s a simplification of my *production* model-code:

```py
class Config(dict):
  # ..

  def as_dict(self) -> dict:
    return self._serialize()

class ModelConfig(Config):
  hidden_size: int = 123
```

Now, I have a custom keras Model which is implemented like this:

```py
class MyModel(keras.Model):

  def __init__(self, config: ModelConfig):
    self.config = config

    self.dense = layers.Dense(config.hidden_size)
    # ...

  def get_config():
    return self.config.as_dict()
```

Everything works except calling `MyModel#save`:

```py
model.save(model_path, save_format='tf')
```

I am getting a `TypeError` saying:

```
TypeError: ('Not JSON Serializable:', <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=123.0>)
```

I know it's `ModelConfig#hidden_size` that is being the property that's becoming a Tensor/EagerTensor here.

The weird thing here is that in one of my test-scripts everything is working as intended. I created it in order to see if `Config` causes a problem on `save()` but this appears not to be the case:

So the following here **is working as expected**:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

from config import Config


class ModelConfig(Config):
    hidden_size: int = 123


class MyLayer(layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, config, other=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.config = config
        self.other = other if other is not None else None
        self.dense = layers.Dense(config.hidden_size + 1)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        x = self.other(inputs, **kwargs) if self.other is not None else inputs
        return self.dense(x, **kwargs)


class MyModel(keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, config: ModelConfig, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.config = config
        self.other = MyLayer(config, other=MyLayer(config))
        self.dense = layers.Dense(config.hidden_size)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        x = self.dense(inputs, **kwargs)
        return self.other(x, **kwargs)

    def get_config(self):
        return self.config.to_dict()

    @tf.function(
        input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None, 100))]
    )
    def infer(self, inputs):
        return self.call(inputs)


def main():
    fp = '/tmp/mymodel'
    config = ModelConfig()
    model = MyModel(config)
    model(np.random.rand(1, 100))
    model.save(fp, save_format='tf')
    model = tf.saved_model.load(fp)
    print(model.infer(np.random.rand(1, 100)))

    print('All done.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This means the problem is not the `Config` object but for some reason in my production-model one of its properties is causing it to fail on calling `save()`.

It's probably a big shot but does anybody have an idea where to look for the issue here?

In one case the property becomes a Tensor/EagerTensor which cannot be serialized (which makes sense) and in the test-script case it stays an `int` which works as intended..

I also tried `tf.saved_model.save` with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is tf.Tensor that is not JSON Serializable.
You can try to convert an object of tf.Tensor to a numpy array, then you should be able to save the config for later reloading.